# Tratar retorno com erro no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Uma chamada para o método excluir esta me retornando o seguinte erro.

> Error Number:
>
> > ERROR: update or delete on table "matricula" violates foreign key constraint "matricula_matricula_cobranca_fk" on table "movimento_cobranca" DETAIL: Key (matricula)=(1908) is still referenced from table "movimento_cobranca".
> >
> > DELETE FROM matricula WHERE matricula IN (1908)
> >
> > Filename: models/Matricula_model.php
> >
> > Line Number: 166

---

Porém eu preciso tratar esse erro e exibir um mensagem para o usuario apenas informando que não funcionou.

No controller estou apenas validando a entrada e chamando no Model.

**Controller**

```
public function excluir($matricula) {
   if ($this->matricula_model->excluir($matricula)->dbReturn === true)
     echo json_encode(['codigo' => 0]);
   else
     echo json_encode(['codigo' => 1]);
}
```

**Model**

```
function excluir($matricula)
{
    if ( $lista_matricula != "" ) {
        $sql_exclusao = "DELETE FROM matricula WHERE matricula IN (". $matricula .")";
        if (!$ret = $this->db->query($sql_exclusao))
        {
            return $this->buildReturnObject($this->db->error(),false);
        }
        return $this->buildReturnObject('',$ret);
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Eu sei o porque do erro estar ocorrendo e não preciso tratar ele no momento (pois é referente ao bd). O que preciso é uma forma de retornar um valor para minha view (utilizei booleanos, mas poderia ser qualquer outro) para poder exibir um alert, uma mensagem ou qualquer que fosse. Eu preciso que meu retorno seja true ou false para passar para minha view um codigo (0 ou 1) e exibir de acordo com ele uma mensagem, porém do jeito que fiz não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o tratamento de erros de banco você pode criar uma nova classe **no core do CI com 'extends' do CI_Model** e criar uma função para gerar um objeto com com o retorno de sucesso e/ou erro.

Exemplo da função na nova Classe:

```
class CustomModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function buildReturnObject($dbError,$dbReturn)
    {
        $retObj = new stdClass();
        $retObj->dbError = $dbError;
        $retObj->dbReturn = $dbReturn;
        return $retObj;
    }
}
```

E pode criar tratamentos na função do seu Model **negando a query (erro) em uma verificação `IF`** (será TRUE caso ocorra algum erro na query), e caso ocorra você pode retornar o objeto criado com o erro ocasionado, caso não ocorra você retorna o objeto com o retorno com sucesso da query, exemplo de como ficaria dentro da sua função no model:

```
if (!$ret = $this->db->query($sql, $binds))
{
    return $this->buildReturnObject($this->db->error(),false);
}
return $this->buildReturnObject('',$ret);
```

Assim quando você receber um resultado não esperado no Controller você trata por lá o que deseja fazer. Não pode esquecer que para poder utilizar a nova função criada para manipular o objeto de retorno, **toda Model que criar devera extender sua classe `CustomModel`**.

Lembrando que no Controller, caso use esse formato, você sempre terá que referenciar a posição `->dbReturn` após o final da consulta, caso algo de errado essa posição receberá false, e você pode acessar o retorno do erro em `->dbError`. A consulta sempre seguira essa sintaxe:

```
$this->classe_model->getXXX($param)->dbReturn;
```

Comment: Tentei fazer com esse método mas sem sucesso. Editei a pergunta da maneira que tentei.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti teria uma maneira de mostrar como você tentou? Pois eu utilizo dessa maneira e não tem erro, sempre que houver erro no banco será retornado false para o Controller. Podemo ir no chat se quiser

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta da maneira que tentei, da uma olhada ver se você entende, se não podemos ir no chat sim sem problemas.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti só pra confirmar, você criou a nova classe no Core do CI e colocou ela extendendo essa sua Model?

E também nesse formato, tome sempre como partido verificar se o dbReturn é false e jogar no else o True se for o caso. Pois com certeza sempre que der erro será retornado False, mas nem sempre que der certo o retorno sera um "true".

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti pode me informar o que retornou sua consulta?

Comment: Eu coloquei ela dentro do CI_Model, por que não da para estender mais de 1 classe, e o CI model precisa ser estendido. (me corrija se estiver errado), o retorno ta sendo o mesmo erro que coloquei como citação na pergunta.

Comment: Sim, realmente precisa estender o CI_Model, mas é por isso que na nova Classe você deve estende-la com o CI_Model, assim todos que forem estendidos pela sua nova classe já terão também o CI_Model, não cheguei a testar com a função direto no CI_Model então não posso confirmar se realmente funciona, posso testar.

Comment: Eu tentei direto com ela no CI_Model pra evitar o trabalho de criar uma classe nova, e aparentemente não funcionou da maneira que fiz, se puder testar a gente já tira a prova. caso funciona-se eu ia criar uma classe nova para ela e dai eu organizava certinho.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti perdão a demora. Eu testei com o CI_Model e funcionou sim. Eu vi que no código do meu post tem um erro, escrevi a função como 'buildReturnObject' e chamo 'buildReturnObj', deveria ser o mesmo nome, por acaso você não acabou replicando-o?

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti e alterou sua verificação para validar o 'false' no IF invés de 'true'?

Comment: Putz, eu repliquei o seu e nem me dei conta, vou testar aqui mudando.

Comment: Alterei para `buildReturnObject`, mas nada mudou :(

Comment: Cara, se eu disser tu não acredita, não tava funcionando porque estava em `development` e não em `production`. Mas de qualquer forma gostei dessa forma que você me passou e vou começar a usar. Marquei como resolvida.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Use Try Catch para tratar exceção.

Comment: Já havia tentando utilizar um bloco Try/Catch, mas sem sucesso

Comment: tente dessa maneira        $this->db->simple_query('SELECT `example_field` FROM `example_table`');

$error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'

Comment: Com o simple_query funciona, porém o js não ta pegando o valor.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte para ver se teve sucesso ou não no model:

```
if(!$sql_exclusao){
    tratamento da excessão...
}
```

Ou algo do tipo. Onde $sql_exclusao vai ser bool se deu certo ou não a query. Não sei se o ambiente que você usa permite, mas o php tem esse poder de saber se a query retornou bem ou não.

Comment: Sem sucesso, somente aparece o erro que coloquei no post e nada de true ou false.

Comment: Já tentou ver esse manual do PHP sobre excessões? Tem uns exemplares bons: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Já vi sim, mas sem sucesso. O retorno é sempre o erro e não um true ou false para mim tratar no controller e exibir para o usuario